# User ID to Profile Picture Relationship

Tags: metadata

Where is the relationship between user's profile photos and their user ID? We are doing an org migration and need to move the photos and remap them back to their user ID in the new org.

Answer (score 1):

The fields you are looking for are `SmallPhotoUrl` and `FullPhotoUrl`.